# A singular integral along the arc and an interval

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration, singular-integrals

Is there a way to solve such and integral:
$$\int_L\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{z})}{z(1-z)} \mathrm dz$$
$L$ can be:

1. an arc of a semicircle with unit radius, centered at the origin and running clockwise from $1$ to $-1$ in the lower half of complex plane of variable $z$;
2. an interval along the $\Re(z)$ axe from $1$ to $-1$.

By the way, I got used to the contours running counterclockwise. What do I need to change the direction? Change the limis of integration and invert the sign of the integral?

Ho to work with the essential singularity at $z=0$ in the econd case?

Comment: In either case the integral is divergent because the integrand has a pole of order $1$ at $z=1$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $$\int_L \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right)}{z(1-z)}\,dz$$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

Changing variables to $\zeta=1/z$, this becomes
$$\int_1^{-1} \frac{\sin\left(\frac1z\right)}{1-z}\frac{\text dz}{z}
=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin\left(\zeta\right)}{\zeta-1}{\text d\zeta}.$$
This integral is divergent at $\zeta=1$ (so the original one was divergent at $z=1$). However, if you change the sine to $\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)$ you introduce a zero at $\zeta=1$ which makes the integral convergent. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D+%5Csin%28pi+z%29%2F%28z-1%29+dz) will happily calculate this for you. You can also reduce this, by changing to $t=1-\zeta$, to the canonical form of the [sine integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), as
$$\int_1^{-1} \frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)}{1-z}\frac{\text dz}{z}
=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin\left(\pi\zeta\right)}{\zeta-1}{\text d\zeta}
=-\int_{0}^{2} \frac{\sin\left(\pi t\right)}{t}{\text dt}
=-\text{Si}(2\pi).$$
This cannot be reduced further in terms of elemental functions, but it is as easy to calculate, in most serious contexts, as any other special function.